# Replacing manually written date with a string containing it

Tags: ruby

I have these 2 things I am working with:

```
CSV.foreach('datafile.csv','r') {|row| D_Location << row[0]}

puts Date.new(2003,05,02).cwday
```

In the first line I would like to change the datafile.csv to something like a string so I can change one string and it changes for all of these codes. I have many, each controlling 1 csv column.

In the second one I would like to replace the actual date written, and replace it with a string. This is so that can be automatic, because the string will be generated based on other criteria.

I trust the mods will ban me if I'm being too much of a noob hehe. Then I'll toughen up and find these answers myself eventually. But so far I've solved a lot, but not this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want and the output you get?

Comment: With the "puts Date.new(2003,05,02).cwday" the output I get is 5, and that is exactly what I want to do when that date is selected. However I want the date to be controlled by a string. So if I could just enter a string name in there instead of the day that would be great. But it doesn't seem to work. - and whoops yeah kind of a noob solution by me ehh. Of course that doesn't work, it needs to know what day it is, what month and such, and not just a sentence. Hmm

Comment: Like Date.new(2003,05,'Tuesday').cwday ?

Comment: Nope I mean like the whole thing. So I don't have to manually enter any day. Lets say my program picks a date based on something, this needs to be able to get that date. This shouldn't be left to the programmer. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function which takes in a string representing a weekday, and returns a number. Call this function later in your code:

```
Date.new(2003, 05, yourfun('Tuesday')).cwday
```

Comment: Let me know if I got what you want to do, else I will just delete this answer.

Comment: No this is good. I'm realizing this obviously needs to be broken up. It won't work to just have a string of the entire y,m,d. - Ok so I will take the string date that my program "generates". And I will break it up into year, month and date. And enter it into those sections in the way you explained. Something like that right?

Comment: @user1594138, you learn fast, you will be a great programmer.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, you're already working with a string.  I think what you mean is that you want it to be in a variable:

```
csv_file = 'datafile.csv'
CSV.foreach(csv_file,'r') {|row| D_Location << row[0]}
```

For the second part of your question, `Date.parse()` works with strings, but they need to be in a format that it can recognize.  If your date strings use commas, you can replace them with hyphens:

```
date_str = "2003,05,02"
Date.parse(date_str.gsub(",", "-")).cwday # => 5
```

It's not clear where your date strings will be coming from or what format they'll be in, but the general concepts you need to understand are that you can use variables, and that you can transform strings.

Comment: Ahh of course, that first part should have been obvious. But who knows if I had ever figured it out, being this new to programming. Thank you sir! As for the second part, the other answer already figured it out for me. I just break down the date into year, month, day, have those in strings and point to the correct string in each section. Just like you explained I think.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out from the other answer; I don't personally think that answer addresses either of your questions.  Yes, parsing the date yourself might be a good option; it all depends.  In many cases calling `Date.parse()` will be easier.

Comment: Well its always the same format for where I get the dates from. It's 4 letters,2,2. So 2001,01,01 - never changes to 2001,1,1. So I can simply chop / slice or split by comma would probably work no matter what. Then I just name these year, month, and day. And put them into the cwday thing. Heh I hope it doesn't hurt how unprofessional I talk about these things. "the cwday thing" xD

Comment: But ok I'll look at the Date.parse() as well.

Comment: In that case, replacing the comma with a hyphen and calling `Date.parse()`, as in my answer, would definitely be easiest.